# how to make a function readonly

Tags: bash, function, readonly

Having a sample function

```
function functionName ()
{
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

How can I avoid it to be overwritten by a following function with the same name?

```
function functionName ()
{
    echo "this is another function"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the -f option to make corresponding function readonly and syntax is:

```
readonly -f functionName
```

After this, if you ever try to update the function an error will be fired:

```
bash: functionName: readonly function
```

Comment: Though, you can still `unset functionName`.

Comment: @choroba: yes you can. I think the above is only to avoid incidental update. If you use unset you really want to update your function, I guess. Thank for the head-up btw.

Comment: @choroba With bash 5.0.17 you cannot.

Comment: @JakubNowak: Which I clearly didn't know in 2012 ;-) Thanks for the update.

Comment: note that this is a "bashism". it doesn't work in busybox ash nor in debian dash